# How to tell apt-get that a package is OK and does not need any more attention

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have a broken Ubuntu 14.04 server. Everything is OK except for apt-get, which for some reason **thinks** that it repeatedly fails to update mysql server package. The mysql server is updated and works perfectly, so I do not want apt-get to touch it. But every time I do anything that includes apt-get update and apt-get install (including installing completely unrelated packages), it always tries to finish the installation of mysql server.

What I am looking for is to find the source of this information that tells apt-get that mysql server needs its attention. I would like to manually edit that source of information and tell apt-get that this package is all OK and it should not care about it anymore.

Is this possible?

Please note that I am not very interested in actually making apt-get to finish the mysql server update. This is because mysql server runs in production there and everytime apt-get tries to "fix it", it kills it and corrupts the database.

If it is not possible to change that apt-get status about a package, would it be possible to somehow tell apt-get not to care about mysql server at all (i.e. to somehow exclude mysql server package from apt-get completely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to tell apt-get not to care about updating a package, it's to put a hold on it:

```
sudo apt-mark hold your_mysql_package
```

More about this [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto). (Not the "pinning" part, but the "holding" part)

Now, as something is broken in your server, it's hard to tell if this will solve your case. And of course, a downside to this is you won't know about any possibly necessary update, later.